# Open a binary File

Tags: c, fopen

in one of my exercice I have to open a folder thanks to C. I do this with the library of dirent, after that I success to display to the screen the name of every file in the Folder. But now, I want to open every time the current file that have been print to the screen. So I do this with a fopen but every time my fopen returns me NULL what can I do in order to open every time the current file.
Thanks you !

Here is my code :

```
void OpenDirectory(char *Folder, char *Virus){
DIR * dir = NULL;
struct dirent* CurrentFile = NULL;

dir = opendir(Folder);
if (dir == NULL){
    perror("");
}
else
{
    while ((CurrentFile = readdir(dir))!= NULL)
    {
        if (!strcmp(CurrentFile->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(CurrentFile->d_name, ".."))
        {
            // Don't do anything
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Current file is : %s\n", CurrentFile->d_name);
            Myfile(CurrentFile->d_name);
        }
    }
}


}

void Myfile(FILE* File1){
File1 = fopen(File1, "rb");
printf("File is : %s", File1);
if (File1 == NULL)
{
    printf("The file source doesn't exist !\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Welcome");
}
}
```

Comment: Show the actual print out, ie. what file specification is printed out by 'printf("File is : %s", File1);'.  Obviously, for the fopen() to work, this needs to be a valid name AND PATH.

Comment: How can I do because the folder who contains all the file is not in the same directory of my program .c

Comment: You must append the filename to the specification of the folder containing it, (strcat).

Comment: Also, using the same var name: 'File1', for both the fine specification and the file descriptor token in Myfile() is VERY confusing!

Comment: `CurrentFile->d_name` is an array of `char` - passing it to a function which expects a `FILE *` (not to mention passing a `FILE *` to `printf()` when it's expecting a `char *`, and *before* you've checked it against `NULL`) is only going to lead to tears. Your compiler should be screaming warnings at you.

Answer (score 1):

The directory contains filenames.

So the first filename might be `foo`, and that's what you will get out of the dirent. So then you try to open it, effectively doing `fopen("foo", "r");`.

But that means "Open the file named `foo` *in the current working directory*". Since the file is in some subdirectory, it won't be found.

One solution is to `cwd` to the directory each time you start to work on a new directory. That works fine; the challenge is returning to the parent directory when you are done.